# Accessing to different objects properties in a iterative way in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm working with angularjs to hide/show columns, the problem is that i load the table header from a json file like this:

```
<th ng-repeat="indicador in indicadores[0].opciones" 
    ng-show="filtro[indicador.id_n]" style="text-align: center; width:200px;">
        {{indicador.abr}}
</th>
```

that code loads all the possible headers, so if the user decides to see certain column, that column show up.

but the problem is that the data from the columns also cames from another json file, the thing is that the total of columns are 32, those 32 columns are distributed in 6 objects (for example the user wants to see 4 properties in columns from object A and 3 from object C).

My question here is how i can write code to show each column that the user selects to see without coding one by one, like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="cuadrado"  ng-show="filtro[0]"
        ng-repeat="localidad in pueblo.localidades | filter:busqueda  | orderBy:'nombre'">
            {{localidad.oferta.ecas}}
    </div>
</td> <!--and the rest 31 cols go below-->
```

i need an iterative way to do this, access to different objects in the json file an their nested properties in an iterative way.
here is my json to which i use to fill the cols with data: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=431cdc8fdd1b10a8acb202a1cbbc2082

**NOTE:** if it has any use, back then i only showed one property per object in one column, so the user only could select one property at the time, my code was this:

```
<td>
    <div class="cuadrado" 
        ng-repeat="localidad in pueblo.localidades | filter:busqueda  | orderBy:'nombre'">
        {{localidad.oferta[tipoIndicador[0]]}}
    </div>
</td>
```

**EDIT**: i have  been reading forums and found this

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">{{key}}: {{val}}</li>
</ul>
```

make this

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: John</li>
    <li>Phone: (123) 456-7890</li>
    <li>Country: England</li>
</ul>
```

this way i can access different type of objects dynamically without knowing all the names of the properties, i made some test and works, but i still don't know how to access to most nested elements of my object in an iterative way.

Comment: The link you posted to your JSON does not show your JSON document. You need to save it first so you get a unique URL for your document. Please update.

Comment: @GPicazo i updated the post, sorry i derped.

Comment: I recommend that instead of creating a very tricky and hard to read template, you build a representation of your data that is based on nested arrays and lends itself well to rendering with ng-repeat. I mean a representation separate from the json you already have. In short: Write JS code to create the simpler model and keep the template simple.

Comment: I agree with lex82, so I guess a good answer might suggest how to do that. Can you post an example of the json file used to render the headers as well as the definition of the 'filtro' function?

Comment: ok i did it! it took me while to figure out how